# Is the "Clock Drawing Test" for encephalitis assessed in the same way as screening for dementia?

Tags: cognitive-science, dementia

The Clock Drawing Test (CDT) is quite pervasive in the field of neuropsychology "quickly assess[ing] visuospatial and praxis abilities, and may determine the presence of both attention and executive dysfunctions" -- [Canadian Partnership for Stroke Studies](http://www.strokengine.ca/assess/cdt/). It seems to be used the most for Dementia and Alzheimer's. (You can also watch many YouTube videos of the Clock Drawing Test being administered [screening for Dementia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hRBPrfDQVI)).

**Is the "Clock Drawing Test" for encephalitis assessed in the same way as screening for dementia?**

I was reading [*Brain on Fire: My Month of Madness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_on_Fire) by Susannah Cahalan, about a woman who was diagnosed with encephalitis through this Clock Drawing Test. **SPOILER ALERT:**

> Dr. Najjar diagnosed Cahalan using a test that involved her drawing a
> clock, a test normally given to people suspected of having dementia or
> Alzheimer's disease. Rather than drawing the clock face normally, the
> disease caused Cahalan to draw all of the numbers 1 through 12 on the
> right face of the clock, because the right side of her brain, which
> regulates the left side of the body, was inflamed. Najjar used this to
> help diagnose Cahalan and start her road to recovery. -Wikipedia link above ^^

**Is the way Cahalan drew the clock different than how a person with Dementia would draw the clock?**

**How is the doctor able to distinguish Dementia from Encephalitis on the Clock Drawing Test?**